# Compare two coordinate values of an image

Tags: matlab

i have set of co-ordinate values and i want to compare these values with each other. I want x-min, x-max,y-min ,y-max as result.
For example :
(10,40)
and
(20,30)
are two set of values.
i want to compare them;
it should be the result:

```
x-min=10
y-min=30
x-max=20
y-max=40
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have separate arrays for `x` and `y`, see @Andrey's answer. 
If you have an array like

```
A = [x y] = [
    10 40
    20 30
    ..
    90 25];
```

then use this:

```
mins = min(A);
maxs = max(A); 

minX = mins(1);   maxX = maxs(1);
minY = mins(2);   maxY = maxs(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds easy:

```
max(x(:));  %#Get the maximal value.
min(x(:));  %#Get the minimal value.
max(y(:));  %#Get the maximal value.
min(y(:));  %#Get the minimal value.
```

Now you can compare them.