# store data in array from loop in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

I want to store data coming from for-loops in an array. How can I do that?
sample output:

```
for x=1:100
    for y=1:100

        Diff(x,y) = B(x,y)-C(x,y);

        if (Diff(x,y) ~= 0)

            % I want to store these values of coordinates in array
            % and find x-max,x-min,y-max,y-min
            fprintf('(%d,%d)\n',x,y);


        end
    end
end
```

Can anybody please tell me how can i do that. Thanks

Marry

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192810/compare-two-coordinate-values-of-an-image/12192936#12192936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want lists of the x and y (or row and column) coordinates at which B and C are different. I assume B and C are matrices. First, you should vectorize your code to get rid of the loops, and second, use the find() function:

```
Diff = B - C;  % vectorized, loops over indices automatically
[list_x, list_y] = find(Diff~=0);  
   % finds the row and column indices at which Diff~=0 is true
```

Or, even shorter,

```
[list_x, list_y] = find(B~=C);
```

Remember that the first index in matlab is the row of the matrix, and the second index is the column; if you tried to visualize your matrices B or C or Diff by using imagesc, say, what you're calling the X coordinate would actually be displayed in the vertical direction, and what you're calling the Y coordinate would be displayed in the horizontal direction. To be a little more clear, you could say instead

```
[list_rows, list_cols] = find(B~=C);
```

To then find the maximum and minimum, use

```
maxrow = max(list_rows);
minrow = min(list_rows);
```

and likewise for list_cols.

Comment: I made an edit to show max and min now, but you could find that in the help on your own too :)

Answer (score 1):

If `B(x,y)` and `C(x,y)` are functions that accept matrix input, then instead of the double-for loop you can do

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:100);
Diff  = B(x,y)-C(x,y);

mins  = min(Diff);
maxs  = max(Diff);

min_x = mins(1);    min_y = mins(2);
max_x = maxs(1);    max_y = maxs(2);
```

If `B` and `C` are just matrices holding data, then you can do

```
Diff = B-C;
```

But really, I need more detail before I can answer this completely.

So: are `B` and `C` functions, matrices? You want to find `min_x`, `max_x`, but in the example you give that's just `1` and `100`, respectively, so...what do you mean?